# How to combine bootstrap 3 form-control input with hidden true

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and have a little issue. It is better explained with the code:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="id" hidden="true"/>
```

I expect this input to be hidden, but looks like form-control css display property overrides hidden one.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
[hidden], template {
    display: none;
}
```

I do see in chrome dev-tools that hidden's display has strikethrough.

I know that bootstrap has "hidden" class and it works, but I would expect that hidden attribute would work too. Isn't it a bug?

Thanks

Comment: why would u style a hidden field ???

Comment: Hm, because I want to unhide it some point. But I think you are right, it is quite stupid and it is definitely better to use class hidden here instead if attribute.

Comment: as an answer to what u want u can use either `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` check http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_display_visibility.asp or `opacity: 0;` and u can unhide with either css or js.

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: good idea ,also to make it easier to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to what you want, you can use either `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`

Check http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_display_visibility.asp or use `opacity: 0;` and you can unhide with either CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this in your custom css

```
[hidden], template {
display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: I think ~ctf0 is right and I misused hidden attribute. Anyway, thanks.